# What is the meaning of php-fpm slowlog first field?

Tags: performance, php

What is the meaning of the hex value in php-fpm slowlog?

Ex:

```
[28-Jan-2014 05:37:04]  [pool example] pid 30651
script_filename = /www/example/index/app.php-fpm
[0x0000000001a12d00] sleep() /www/example/application/controllers/MController.php:51
[0x0000000001a12740] sleepAction() /www/example/zendframework/Zend/Controller/Action.php:513
[0x0000000001a11928] dispatch() /www/example/zendframework/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:289
[0x0000000001a0ff00] dispatch() /www/example/zendframework/Zend/Controller/Front.php:954
[0x0000000001a0dd88] dispatch() /www/example/index/app.php-fpm:244
```

Memory address in the call stack? Execution time in Hex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's internal call number of the method, not execution time. I think it exists for helping developers when deep-tracing the code using a profiling dump.

Link: [source code of the fpm_request.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_request.c)